# Women in mathematics.

Tags: reference-request, math-history, popular-math

I'd like to read something about the history of women in mathematics. I'd love to have reading suggestions of books in English or Italian, of 3 kinds:

1) History of math books, academic style;

2) Popular mathematics books, for a broader audience;

3) Books for young girls (8-11yo), possibly in Italian.

Thanks.

Comment: While this is a perfectly good question, I believe it belongs on a different site. I think there's a site for the history of science and mathematics.

Comment: You can see [this post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/what-famous-theorems-or-results-were-proven-by-female-mathematicians).

Comment: I think this question is best suited for the site https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I'll love my questione to hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: One question for the thought police here: Should I delete all my answers and questions regardings history of mathematics on mse?